# Python | Twitter API | how do I get latest tweets from a particular person imediatly

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweets

im wondering how do i read tweets live from a particular person using python and twitter API
please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Using Apache Spark Streaming you can fetch live Tweets from a user. The following guide does #Trending tweets, but I'm sure you can do it for a particular user, in Python: https://www.toptal.com/apache/apache-spark-streaming-twitter

Make sure you have access to Twitter so you can get your API keys for this to work. Here are the instructions for that: https://www.slickremix.com/docs/how-to-get-api-keys-and-tokens-for-twitter/